# SELECT without FROM<table> but with APPLY / JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, optimization

I write a procedure and need few foreign key id's for further operations

table `md_machines`

```
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
| 1  | c432  |
| 2  | c431  |
| n  | ...   |
+----+-------+
```

my query within my procedure:

```
SELECT TOP 1  
@m1 = m1.id,  
@m2 = m2.id,  
@m3 = m3.id,  
@m4 = m4.id  
FROM md_machines  
OUTER APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 id FROM md_machines WHERE name = @p1) m1  
OUTER APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 id FROM md_machines WHERE name = @p2) m2  
OUTER APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 id FROM md_machines WHERE name = @p3) m3  
OUTER APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 id FROM md_machines WHERE name = @p4) m4
```

All works fine, but `md_machines` has over 300k rows. When I replace `FROM md_machines` with an empty table, then this query is roughly 10% faster.
How can I avoid `FROM md_machines`? It's not necessary for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select them once

```
SELECT name, min(id) 
FROM md_machines 
WHERE (name = @p1 or name = @p2 or name = @p3 or name = @p4)
group by name
```

and then use the query above by `WITH`

```
WITH sub (name, id)  
AS  
(  
    the suquery  
)

SELECT TOP 1
@m1 = m1.id,
@m2 = m2.id,
@m3 = m3.id,
@m4 = m4.id
FROM (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM sub WHERE name = @p1) m1,
     (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM sub WHERE name = @p2) m2,
     (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM sub WHERE name = @p3) m3,
     (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM sub WHERE name = @p4) m4
```

BTW: would be nice to have index on the `name` column

UPDATE: I think this one will work as well

```
SELECT TOP 1
@m1 = m1.id,
@m2 = m2.id,
@m3 = m3.id,
@m4 = m4.id
FROM (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM md_machines WHERE name = @p1) m1,
     (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM md_machines WHERE name = @p2) m2,
     (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM md_machines WHERE name = @p3) m3,
     (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM md_machines WHERE name = @p4) m4
```

Comment: nice solution/work around. i will remember it especially because usage of `min`and `group` for another projects. here i use unique index for `name`column and primary key for `id`

Answer (score 2):

Use simple variable assignment:

```
SET @m1 = (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM md_machines WHERE name = @p1);
SET @m2 = (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM md_machines WHERE name = @p2);
SET @m3 = (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM md_machines WHERE name = @p3);
SET @m4 = (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM md_machines WHERE name = @p4);
```

`TOP 1` without explicit `ORDER BY` is not stable.

Comment: Yeah, this was my first version of code. But multiple queries are eating more performance. So i was going to JOIN / APPLY